# What determines the order of Symbols returned from Object.getOwnPropertySymbols?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

ES2015 defines a new method on `Object`, `getOwnPropertySymbols`.  I'm using this to get all of the symbol keys from an object I have:

```
let syms = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(myObj);
```

Previously, I was operating under the assumption that the return order was determined by sorting the string version of the symbols.  A quick test showed that was wrong:

```
let obj = {};
obj[Symbol('Stack')] = 'Stack';
obj[Symbol('Overflow')] = 'Overflow';
Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj); // [ Symbol(Stack), Symbol(Overflow) ]
```

How is this determined?  Is it the order they're added to the global Symbol registry, or just "random" like regular `Object.keys`?

Comment: insertion order, just like other properties, except expando-capable keys, which are numerically sorted, but those are not symbols, so just insertion.

Comment: @dandavis this was a self-answer, check my answer below!  If I've missed anything, please let me know

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: @dandavis So he can share what he learned

Comment: @dandavis as nick said, so I can share what I learned.  This was faster than a full blog post (and more likely to help people).  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 2):

Every JavaScript Object has an internal tracker named [OwnPropertyKeys](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys).  This is a List that tracks all of the keys of the object, string or Symbol.  When you call `getOwnPropertySymbols`, here's what's happening:

1. All `getOwnPropertySymbols` does is call the internal `GetOwnPropertyKeys` with `(O, Symbol)` [[spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getownpropertysymbols)].
2. `GetOwnPropertyKeys` walks through OwnPropertyKeys, adding them to an array if said key is a symbol (since we called it with `Symbol` above). [[spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getownpropertykeys)].
3. The array we created before is returned.

Now at least we know what's going on behind the scenes but how does that determine order?  The key is that `OwnPropertyKeys` is ordered by *the order the keys were added to the object*.  So this has nothing to do with when the symbol was added to the registry, as shown here:

```
let symO = Symbol('Overflow');
let symS = Symbol('Stack');
let obj = {};
obj[symS] = 'Stack';
obj[symO] = 'Overflow';
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)); // [ Symbol(Stack), Symbol(Overflow) ]
```

Even though we *declared* the symbols in reverse order, all `getOwnPropertySymbols` cares about is the order they were added to the object.